# Crystal Report converted from Data Flex to SQL now getting formula errors

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2011

Here is my formula:

```
if Maximum({@tx plan date}, {CDCLIENT.SORT_NAME})=Date (1999-01-01) then 
  currentdate-Maximum ({CDASSFRM.DATE_EFFECTIVE}, {CDCLIENT.SORT_NAME}) 
else 
  Maximum ({@tx plan date}, {CDCLIENT.SORT_NAME})-Maximum ({CDASSFRM.DATE_EFFECTIVE}, {CDCLIENT.SORT_NAME})
```

The above formula is now getting a string is required error on the field `=Date(1999-01-01)` part. I don't seem to be able to figure what is needed

Comment: Have you tried wrapping `1999-01-01` in either apostrophes (`'`) or quotes (`"`)?

Comment: yes te response was the same

Answer (score 0):

To declare a date in Crystal reports you can use a hash:

```
Date (#1999-01-01#)
```

**Edit**

As you are trying to compare to s tring you need to convert either the string to a date or vise versa (might need to test and play around with the date formats):

```
if Maximum({@tx plan date}, {CDCLIENT.SORT_NAME})= "1999-01-01" then ToText(currentdate-Maximum ({CDASSFRM.DATE_EFFECTIVE}, {CDCLIENT.SORT_NAME}),"yyyy-MM-dd") else 
Date(Maximum ({@tx plan date}, {CDCLIENT.SORT_NAME}))-Maximum ({CDASSFRM.DATE_EFFECTIVE}, {CDCLIENT.SORT_NAME})
```

Comment: The response is the same that a string is required

Comment: @user2528135, which version of crystal reports are you using?

Comment: Also, is the data type of `{@tx plan date}` definitely a date?

Comment: Crystal Report version 2011. The {@tx plan date] is a string field

Comment: @user2528135, added more detail

Comment: Thank you for all your time with this however I still receive a string error.

Comment: A good test is to add a formula that is just a single part of the formula, this will then show you where the error lies.

Answer (score 0):

Use either:

```
if Maximum({@tx plan date}, {CDCLIENT.SORT_NAME})=Date(1999,01,01) then 
  currentdate-Maximum ({CDASSFRM.DATE_EFFECTIVE}, {CDCLIENT.SORT_NAME}) 
else 
  Maximum ({@tx plan date}, {CDCLIENT.SORT_NAME})-Maximum ({CDASSFRM.DATE_EFFECTIVE}, {CDCLIENT.SORT_NAME})
```

or:

```
if Maximum({@tx plan date}, {CDCLIENT.SORT_NAME})=DateValue("1999-01-01") then 
  currentdate-Maximum ({CDASSFRM.DATE_EFFECTIVE}, {CDCLIENT.SORT_NAME}) 
else 
  Maximum ({@tx plan date}, {CDCLIENT.SORT_NAME})-Maximum ({CDASSFRM.DATE_EFFECTIVE}, {CDCLIENT.SORT_NAME})
```